# Deploying Django using fcgi causes slow page loading

Tags: python, django, webserver

I need to deploy my django app on a shared server, where I don't have root access (e.g. httpd.conf) andn all I have is the folder public_html.

Now, I followed the sites describing using fcgi to deploy django (e.g. [this](http://blog.kodekabuki.com/post/29578853/tutorial-setting-up-django-on-a-shared-host)). However, the pages load very slowly, I guess the reason is that django needs to be reloaded upon every request? Essentially, I would like a server that runs permanently and simply gets requests from apache.

Before trying out the solution with sockets and so on, I would like to ask for some professional opinions.

thanks!

Comment: Apache's mod_wsgi is way better for django than fcgi. That said, django **is not reloaded upon every request** (FCGI != CGI). You could use django-debug-toolbar maybe it would give you some clues about the page load time.

Comment: Also are you serving images via the django server or directly from your web server?

Comment: thanks! @lian liev, from django server. But at the moment, the page only shows one single string. So I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: @jpic, thanks, could you give me a reference how else django is not reloaded upon every request?

Answer (score 0):

**FCGI sucks**. Even its author admits it.

Using **Apache** ? Try **[mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)**. It's the *most professional* deployment solution for apache.

Using **Nginx or something else** ? Then consider [uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/). or [gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/).

[Link to a benchmark](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/fcgi-vs-gunicorn-vs-uwsgi).

Comment: all wsgi tutorials I read states that I need to modify the httpd.conf file, where I don't have the permission to do so...

Comment: well if you want professional hosting you need a professional host. There are many, gondor.io, ep.io, djangozoom, heroku ... They will handle the deployment for you and it will rock. You can't win a F1 race with a bicycle can you ?

Comment: yes, so far my server has been deployed on webfaction. But I will need some real data processing (upto few 10G of ram), so I just want to deploy it on my univ's computer first before considering buying more expensive subscriptions (Amazon E2)....